# Google Photos API integration in React Native

Tags: react-native, google-photos-api

I am using [React native Google Sign in](https://github.com/react-native-community/google-signin) plugin for authenticating the users, to use google photos API. According to the given documentation of the plugin, I did the configurations. It is working fine on the iOS platform but not on the Android platform.

1. configuring google sign in

   ```
    configureGoogleSignIn = async () => {
     GoogleSignin.configure({
      scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.sharing',
      ],
      shouldFetchBasicProfile: true,
      iosClientId:
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? 'iOS_PLATFORM_CLIENT_ID'
          : 'ANDROID_PLATFORM_CLIENT_ID',
      // offlineAccess: true,
    });
   ```

   };

When I use this code and sign in with an iOS device or simulator it is working fine and return the user details with **idToken** but on the android device, it only returns the user details and idToken as null.

Anybody help me with this